# Heroku : deploy multi-container docker app

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to deploy my app to heroku.

I have a container for the API, a container for the client and another for mysql db.
I have also a volume for the db and two networks for allow api and client interact.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
  
  bpfmgr-api:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./api
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $API_PORT:$API_PORT
    environment:
      - some env variables
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

  bpfmgr-client:
    depends_on:
      - bpfmgr-api
    build:
      context: ./client
      args:
        - VITE_API_URL=$VITE_API_URL
        - VITE_API_KEY=$BPFMGR_API_KEY
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - frontend  

volumes: 
  db:

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

How can I deploy this to heroku ?